# How to disable a button whether radio button is selected or not using angular 2 typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

[image: click here to see screenshot]

I need to disable button whether radio button is selected or not using angular 2 typescript. There are 2 steps in my application

Step 1: after selecting country and username, user is redirected to

Step 2: where there will be a list of radio buttons(depends on user have any party id's in OKta). If the user selects one radio button in step 2 and clicks cancel button, then page redirect step 1.

Now user continues to step 2 the button is not disabled because of the previous selection made. I wrote button [disabled] but still, it didn't work.

```
  <form #addAccountForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="selectParty()" autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="partySelectForm">
                <p i18n>Select the name of the member you wish to associate with this ConnectID.</p>
                <div class="party"
                     *ngFor="let party of (parties | async); let i = index;"
                     [ngClass]="{'connected': party.alreadyConnected}">
                        <span class="party__name_container">
                            <input id="party{{i}}" type="radio"
                                   formControlName="partyId"
                                   [(ngModel)]="selectedParty"
                                   [value]="party"
                                   [attr.disabled]="party.alreadyConnected === true || null"
                                   [attr.selected]="partyCount === 1">
                            <label for="party{{i}}">{{party}}</label>
                        </span>
                    <span *ngIf="party.alreadyConnected" class="party--is-connected"><em>Connected</em></span>
                </div>
                <p class="TAL paddingtop1x" i18n>If this list of members appears incorrect or the name you wish to select is already connected, please contact your local Customer Service representative.</p>
                <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-block margintop2x" type="submit" [disabled]="partySelectForm.controls['partyId'].invalid" i18n>CREATE MY ConnectID</button>

            </form>
```

.ts:

```
export class BusinessPartySelectComponent implements OnInit {
partySelectForm: FormGroup;

parties: Observable<Party[]>;
partyCount: number;

viewData = {
    atLeastOnePartyNotConnected: true,
    hideModal: true
};

// View model
selectedParty: Party;

autoSelectIfOneNonConnectedPartyReturned = true;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            private store: Store<State>) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.partySelectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        partyId: [ '', [ Validators.required ] ],
    });
```

Comment: why do you have 2 form names?  `#addAccountForm="ngForm"` and `[formGroup]="partySelectForm"`?

Comment: @SurajRao Dont know it was written by someone. Is this is the reason?

Comment: both set a formGroup to the html template.. remove addAccountForm and try

Comment: Ok , i will try and let you know.